# Send email one time 20 emails only in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to Send email one time 20 emails only codeIgniter?

When click send button one time send only 20 records.

How to do that ?

Can you give simple code?

Comment: why dont you try to loop 20 times,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about this,but maybe it help

```
$this->load->library('email');

for($a = 0;$a < 20;$a++){
    $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
    $this->email->to('someone@example.com');
    $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
    $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();
 }
```

Comment: looped 20 times.. great idea :)